# Trigger form actions with ACF Extended in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields

I have a "Get a quote" form that has 3 buttons (calculate price, send an email, submit for order).
I want all 3 buttons to save the form. The "calculate price button" runs a js that calculates using ajax the price and updates the "total" field. But I can't find a way to trigger the save action afterwards. The "send an email" button has to calculate price, save then asks to send an email to a 3rd party. The "submit for order" must calculate price, save then send an email to admin.

My js calculate price works well. I've aded my action hooks name in the ACF extended form ui. I've tried hardcoding html buttons on my page template, pasting the html buttons directly into the button field of ACF Extended forms, tried learning how to use the actions hooks in ACF Extended from the official documents, chat GPT and numerous search words on Google. I can't figure how to link the buttons to the action hooks in the ACF Extented form interface.

Any insight for me? I'm open to change my structure of action (like not having a calculate button and it calculates after each field change or something like that).

Here's my form https://ddsignalisation.ca/affiche-sur-mesure/ (French)

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code displaying my form on my page template

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 order-md-2 col-sm-12">
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'content' ); ?>>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php
                the_content();
            ?>

    <?php $post_id = $derniereSoumission ? 'new_post' : 'new_post';
        
        acfe_form(array(
            'id' => 'soumission-affiche',
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'event',
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        ),
        'submit_value'  => 'Sauvegarder'
    )); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
if ($entreprise) :
    $rabaisgroupe = get_field('rabais', $entreprise);
    if (!empty($rabaisgroupe)) :
?>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $('#acf-field_650c2a814e722').val('<?php echo esc_js($rabaisgroupe); ?>');
            });
        </script>
<?php
    endif;
endif;
?>
    </div><!-- /.col -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 order-md-2 col-sm-12">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center ">
            <div class="d-block gp-2">
                <button id="calculate-button" class="mb-1 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="my-action">Calculer <i class="fa-regular fa-floppy-disk"></i></button>
                <button class="mb-1 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="envoyer_par_email">Email <i class="fa-regular fa-envelope"></i></button>
                <button class="mb-1 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="action" value="commander">Commander <i class="fa-regular fa-file-lines"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's my js button code :

```
$("#calculate-button").click(function () {
    var errors = [];
    var largeur = parseFloat($("#acf-field_64fd15022cad9").val(), 10);
    var hauteur = parseFloat($("#acf-field_64fd15472cada").val(), 10);
    var uniteDeMesure = $("input[name='acf[field_64fd155f2cadb]']:checked").val();

    if (uniteDeMesure === "cm") {
        // Convert centimeters to inches
        largeur /= 2.54;
        hauteur /= 2.54;
    }

    var mesures = largeur * hauteur;

    var materiel = $("#acf-field_64fd12182cad3").val();
    var vinyle = $("#acf-field_6501f5609015e").val();
    var protectionuv = 0;
    $(".acf-field-6501f7c490161 input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() === "oui") {
            protectionuv = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });
    var rectoverso = 0;
    $(".acf-field-64fd14742cad8 input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() === "oui") {
            rectoverso = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });

    var trous = 0;
    if (!isNaN(parseInt($("#acf-field_64fd196f2cae0").val(), 10))) {
        trous = parseInt($("#acf-field_64fd196f2cae0").val(), 10);
    } else {
        trous = parseInt($("#acf-field_6501f92690163").val(), 10);
    }

    var qty = parseInt($("#acf-field_6501f49fc30f4").val(), 10);
    var montage = 0;
    $(".acf-field-6501f97e90164 input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && $(this).val() === "oui") {
            montage = 1;
            return false;
        }
    });
    var tempprod = parseFloat($("#acf-field_6501f6fa9015f").val(), 10);
    
    var grouperabais = parseInt($('input[name="acf[field_655ba74c9723e]"]').val(), 10);
    var ajustement = parseFloat($('input[name="acf[field_655ba9ed9bc8b]"]').val(), 10);
    // alert('Rabais : ' + groupe_rabais + '\nAjustement : ' + ajustement);

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert("Les champs suivants ne sont pas numériques : " + errors.join(", "));
        return;
    } else {
        // Si tous les champs sont numériques, effectuez la requête AJAX
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "calculate_price",
                mesures: mesures,
                materiel: materiel,
                vinyle: vinyle,
                rectoverso: rectoverso,
                protectionuv: protectionuv,
                trous: trous,
                montage: montage,
                tempprod: tempprod,
                ajustement: ajustement,
                grouperabais: grouperabais,
                qty: qty,
                
            },
            success: function (response) {
                var data = JSON.parse(response);
                alert(
                    "Mesures en po2 : " +
                        data.mesures +
                        "\nMatériaux : " +
                        data.materiel +
                        "\nVinyle : " +
                        data.vinyle +
                        "\nRecto-verso : " +
                        data.rectoverso +
                        "\nProtection UV : " +
                        data.protectionuv +
                        "\nTrous : " +
                        data.trous +
                        "\nMontage : " +
                        data.montage +
                        "\nQuantité : " +
                        data.qty +
                    "\nTemps de production : " +
                    data.tempprod +
                    "\nAjustement : " +
                    data.ajustement +
                    "\nRabais groupe : " +
                    data.grouperabais +
                        "\nTotal : " +
                        data.total
                );

                $("#acf-field_650c288b4e721").val(data.total.toFixed(2));
            },
        });
    }
});
```

Here's my php function

```
function calculate_price() {

    $mesures = $_POST['mesures'];
    $materiel = $mesures * get_field('prix', sanitize_text_field($_POST['materiel']));
    $vinyle = $mesures * get_field('prix', sanitize_text_field($_POST['vinyle']));
    $protectionuv = $_POST['protectionuv'] == 1 ? get_field("prix", 70) * $mesures : 0;
    $rectoverso = $_POST['rectoverso'] == 1 ? get_field("prix", 71) * ($vinyle + $protectionuv) : 0;
    $trous = $_POST['trous'] * get_field("prix", 72);
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $montage = $_POST['montage'] == 1 ? get_field("prix", 73) : 0;
    $ajustement = $_POST['ajustement'];
    $grouperabais = $_POST['grouperabais'];


    

$prix_calcule = $qty * ($materiel + $vinyle + $protectionuv + $rectoverso + $trous) + $montage;
    $tempprod = get_field("prix", sanitize_text_field($_POST['tempprod']));
    if (empty($tempprod)) { $tempprod=1;}
    $prix_calcule *= $tempprod;
        $grouperabais = $grouperabais / 100;
        $prix_calcule -= $prix_calcule * $grouperabais;
if ($prix_calcule < get_field('prix_minimum', 'options')) {
        $prix_calcule = get_field('prix_minimum', 'options');
    }
    $response = array(
    'mesures' => $mesures,
    'materiel' => $materiel,
    'vinyle' => $vinyle,
    'rectoverso' => $rectoverso,
    'protectionuv' => $protectionuv,
    'trous' => $trous,
    'montage' => $montage,
    'qty' => $qty,
    'tempprod' => '* ' . $tempprod,
            'ajustement' => $ajustement,
            'grouperabais' => $grouperabais,
    'total' => $prix_calcule
);
    echo json_encode($response);

wp_die();
```

}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.